# Preventing duplicate slashes in file paths

Tags: r, filepath

I would like to build a path to a file, given a filename and a folder where that file exists. The folder may include a trailing slash or it may not. In python, `os.path.join` solves this problem for you.  Is there a base R solution to this problem? If not, what is the recommended way in R to build file paths that do not have duplicate slashes?

This works fine:

```
> file.path("/path/to/folder", "file.txt")
[1] "/path/to/folder/file.txt"
```

But if the user provides a folder with a trailing slash, `file.path` does the still-functional-but-annoying double-slash:

```
> file.path("/path/to/folder/", "file.txt")
[1] "/path/to/folder//file.txt"
```

I'm looking for a built-in, 1 function answer to this common issue.

Answer (score 4):

might be os independent, instead of explicitly coding /

```
joinpath = function(...) {
    sep = .Platform$file.sep
    result = gsub(paste0(sep,"{2,}"), sep, file.path(...), fixed=FALSE, perl=TRUE)
    result = gsub(paste0(sep,"$"), '', result, fixed=FALSE, perl=TRUE)
    return(result)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the `//` with `/` using `gsub` if it is too annoying. You could put it in a custom function for ease

```
file.path2 = function(..., fsep = .Platform$file.sep){
    gsub("//", "/", file.path(..., fsep = fsep))
}

file.path2("/path/to/folder", "file.txt")
#[1] "/path/to/folder/file.txt"

file.path2("/path/to/folder/", "file.txt")
#[1] "/path/to/folder/file.txt"
```